# Why is string::find's behavior different?

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, find

```
bool check_tape(char* tape) {
    int test8; 
    cout << example <<" "<<example.size()<<" "<<alpha_sym<<" "<< endl;
    cin >> test8; //To pause the program, temporary 
    int err = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < example.size(); i++) {
        if (alpha_sym.find(example[i]) >= 0 && alpha_sym.find(example[i]) < example.size()) {
            cout << alpha_sym.find(example[i]) << " " << endl;
            err += 0;
        }
        else {
            cout << example[i]<<" "<< i << " не содержится в алфавите" << endl;
            err++;
        }
    }
    if (err) {
        return 1; //Temporary I made here return 1, else program will crash 
        //get_acmd();
    }
    else return 1;
}
```

In one case, `find` returns a position of the first entry as expected, but in other case it returns char itself.
111+11 - string, and chars from it are searching in the other string "1+_"

Same with 1435+212 and 01234567+_

[image: Good case]

[image: Strange case]

Comment: Where does it return the char itself? And whats this condition? Check for `std::string::npos`.

Comment: I would suggest reviewing the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and pay special attention to the "Return value" section.

Comment: @tkausl, why I am getting + on the 5th position instead of 8, because 01234567+_ [8] is '+'

Comment: Because _you_ are printing the char in your else case.

Comment: Seems that there is a typo in `alpha_sym.find(example[i]) < example.size()`. Should be `< alpha_sym.size()`. But generaly this condition absolutelly useless.

Comment: @tkausl, oh, really... Now I found my real mistake

Comment: Wrong way of using find. should be alpha_sym.find(example[i]) != string::npos

Comment: @Zefick, yeah, I noticed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was already noted in a comment to the question there is a typo in the if statement

```
if (alpha_sym.find(example[i]) >= 0 && alpha_sym.find(example[i]) < example.size())
                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Instead of `example.size()` there must be at least `alpha_sym.size()`

But in any case the condition is too complicated and the method `find` is called in general three times.

This snippet of code

```
for (int i = 0; i < example.size(); i++) {
    if (alpha_sym.find(example[i]) >= 0 && alpha_sym.find(example[i]) < example.size()) {
        cout << alpha_sym.find(example[i]) << " " << endl;
        err += 0;
    }
    else {
        cout << example[i]<<" "<< i << " не содержится в алфавите" << endl;
        err++;
    }
}
```

can be rewritten the following way

```
for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < example.size(); i++ )
{
    auto n = alpha_sym.find( example[i] );

    if ( n != std::string::npos )
    {
        std::cout << n << " " << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << example[i] << " " << i << " не содержится в алфавите" << std::endl;
        ++err;        
    }
}
```

If your compiler supports C++ 17 then you can even write the following way

```
for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < example.size(); i++ )
{
    if ( auto n = alpha_sym.find( example[i] ); n != std::string::npos )
    {
        std::cout << n << " " << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << example[i] << " " << i << " не содержится в алфавите" << std::endl;
        ++err;        
    }
}
```

Pay attention to that the unused parameter `tape` of the (I think simplified)  function maybe should be declared like

```
bool check_tape( const char *tape )
```

provided that it is not changed in the function. In this case you will be able to pass string literals as function arguments.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string example( "1435+212" );
    std::string alpha_sym( "01234567+_" );
    unsigned int err = 0;

    for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < example.size(); i++ )
    {
        auto n = alpha_sym.find( example[i] );

        if ( n != std::string::npos )
        {
            std::cout << n << " " << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << example[i] << " " << i << " не содержится в алфавите" << std::endl;
            ++err;        
        }
    }
}
```

Its output is

```
1 
4 
3 
5 
8 
2 
1 
2
```